# Vue2 how to watch a global prototype

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I have this prototype `Vue.prototype.$onWindowLoad = false;`, and in a component I would like to set a watcher on this variable. However I seem to be unable to access the global prototypes or the root instance in the watcher option.

```
watch: {
        '$root.$onWindowLoad': function(){
            console.log("works???");
        }
    }
```

I cannot use `this` inside the watch option unfortunately, is it possible to watch this data?

Comment: what is `$root` for?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `$root` or quotes '' around it, unless you are trying to watch `'$onWindowLoad.property'`.

If `$onWindowLoad` is an object you can use `deep: true` to watch for its properties.

More on that here: [“vuejs watch object”](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/vuejs+watch+object)